# Function asking for input in C

Tags: function, average, scanf

I am writing a code that asks for an input(scanf) one positive number at a time and when a negative number is entered the average of all numbers would be displayed.

so far I have:

`

```
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",&b);
scanf("%d",&d);
 if(a<0)
printf("%d\t",a);
else if (b<0)
printf("%d\t",a);
else if (d<0)
printf("%d\t",(a+b)/2);
```

I'm just a beginner at programming atm and I don't think I'm doing it correctly but I'm not sure. Any help/tips?

Comment: have you learned loops yet?

Comment: Yup. I'm not great at them but I've learned them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it and see if this is what you are looking for:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {
       int n,sum=0,i=0;
       while(1)
       {
           scanf("%d",&n);
           if(n<0)
           break;
           sum+=n;
           i++;
       }
       (i!=0)?(printf("%f",(float)sum/i)):(printf("0"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int a = 0;

    do {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if (a < 0)
            if (counter != 0)
                printf("%f", (float)sum/counter);
            else
                printf("%s", "No numbers entered.");
        else
            sum += a;
        counter++;
    } while (a >= 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with a loop, you do:

```
double input, sum = 0.0;
int count = 0;

do
{
    scanf("%d\t",&input)
    count++;
    sum += input;

   if(input < 0)
     printf("%d", &(sum/count))
} while (input >= 0);
```

I'm not too sure about the syntax for printf, but I think that works